# How to connect to Azure ServiceBus in Quarkus

Tags: azure, kotlin, azureservicebus, quarkus, smallrye

I want to connect to ServiceBus subscription from Quarkus. I found this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/jms-developer-guide?tabs=JMS-20), which suggests to use `ServiceBusJmsConnectionFactory` and I am trying to make it work with smallrye

So far I tried:

```
import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.jms.ServiceBusJmsConnectionFactory
import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.primitives.ConnectionStringBuilder
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory

@ApplicationScoped
class ConnectionFactoryBean {
    @Produces
    fun factory(): ConnectionFactory {
        var connectionStringBuilder = ConnectionStringBuilder("Endpoint=sb://mynamespace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=NAME;SharedAccessKey=KEY");
        return ServiceBusJmsConnectionFactory(connectionStringBuilder, null)
    }
}
```

Then in my application.properties:

```
mp.messaging.incoming.my_topic_name.connector=smallrye-jms
```

And finally to receive messages:

```
@Incoming("my_topic_name")
protected suspend fun receiveMyEvent(myEvent: String) {
    //process
}
```

In terms of versions:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
  <artifactId>service-bus-jms-connection-factory</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.smallrye.reactive</groupId>
  <artifactId>smallrye-reactive-messaging-jms</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

It is failing with "An API incompatibility" error.

What is the correct way to receive messages using Kotlin/Quarkus from Azure ServiceBus?

**UPDATE**
I also tried to follow approach from [Reactive messaging AMQP and Service Bus with Open Liberty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58777966/reactive-messaging-amqp-and-service-bus-with-open-liberty)
For that I dropped 2 listed dependencies, replaced them with

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-reactive-messaging-amqp</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And completely removed `ConnectionFactoryBean`.
For that I face

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Failed to create SSL connection

error. Adding `quarkus.tls.trust-all=true` or `quarkus.ssl.native=true` to properties did not work...

And it is still unclear, how to connect to the subscription? Will it be a change to the `@Incoming` attribute?

Comment: 1.  please add an example connection string (obfuscated version) of your connection string.  with all the "parts" specified (and obfuscated).  2.  Please add your (non "*") IMPORT statements.  (3) add the packages you are referencing and their versions.

Comment: @granadaCoder thanks for the comment, I updated the question with details and also outlined one other approach that I tested

Comment: So "ssl" is more of a "baked in" thing with service bus.  not a "addon" like with http(s).  I am guessing, but I think you may need a certificate.  Again, I'm intelligently guessing.  Maybe read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate?tabs=apex%2Cportal

Comment: actually, without `mp.messaging.incoming.tenant-manager.use-ssl=true` connection works. But I cannot receive any messages. I guess I need to setup address properly somehow for the topic subscription, but not sure how

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Azure SDK libraries (maven artefact - [com.azure.messaging.servicebus](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.azure/azure-messaging-servicebus/7.11.0/jar)) to connect to Service Bus subscription.

For that you will need to create a `ServiceBusProcessorClient` connect to your namespace using usual connection string (available from the azure portal
under access policies), specify `topicName` and `subscriptionName` of it and then wait for messages. Here is an example code:

```
@ApplicationScoped
class ServiceBusClient() {
    private val scope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob())

    fun onStart(@Observes event: StartupEvent) {
        scope.startClient()
    }
    fun onStop(@Observes event: ShutdownEvent) {
        scope.cancel()
    }

    private fun CoroutineScope.startClient() = launch {
        val processorClient: ServiceBusProcessorClient = ServiceBusClientBuilder()
              .connectionString("CONNECTION_STRING")
              .processor()
              .topicName("TOPIC_NAME")
              .subscriptionName("SUBSCRIPTION_NAME")
              .processMessage { receivedMessageContext -> onMessage(receivedMessageContext) }
              .processError { errorContext -> onError(errorContext) }
              .buildProcessorClient()

        processorClient.start()
    }

    private fun onMessage(context: ServiceBusReceivedMessageContext) {
        //Process message
    }

    private fun onError(context: ServiceBusErrorContext) {
        //Handle errors
    }
}
```

You could get the content of the message using `context.message.applicationProperties["PROPERTY_NAME"]`, `context.message.body` or `context.message.subject` as required.

Comment: can u plz support https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74733613/how-to-connect-quarkus-application-with-azure-share-file