# How to connect quarkus application with azure share file

Tags: quarkus, azure-file-share

I want to connect my Quaruks application to my azure file. i found this tutorial but its for `blob-storage`: https://quarkiverse.github.io/quarkiverse-docs/quarkus-azure-services/dev/quarkus-azure-storage-blob.html, is there similar way to connect to azure share file in order to upload files there?

i found for example this way: https://github.com/dherenj84/filemanager but its for springboot, i need for Quarkus application, many thanks

Comment: have you tried [this](https://github.com/dherenj84/filemanager/blob/138ea54b02ceee9743a5e7147564af8499612e31/src/main/java/com/demo/filemanager/service/AzureFileService.java#L135) what errors did you get ?

Answer (score 0):

It's same as blob storage, with the difference of setting the uri to connect to azure services like:

```
String uri = String.format("https://%s.**file**.core.windows.net", blob.getAccount());
```

Meanwhile with blob storage is:

```
String uri = String.format("https://%s.**blob**.core.windows.net", blob.getAccount());
```